# knockout if statement to change page view content

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a dropdown list with two options - each option when selected changes the display of content in the view. How can i wire my dropdown selection to change content to display and hide the other.

Here is what i have:

```
<select data-bind="options: items, value: selectedItem"></select>

//if selectedItem = 'A'
<div class="itemA">....</div>

//if selectedItem = 'B'
<div class="itemB">....</div>

self.items = ko.observable(['A', 'B']);
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
```

UPDATE: I have updated my code to show my observables.

So if selected 'A' from dropdown it will be displayed and 'B' should be hidden

Comment: use `if` which is prefererable(IMHO) check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26448/ .

Comment: @supercool - It would very good approach when the dev is sure that items won't change and when there is not a lot of items. Also it's very interesting from performance perspective visible vs if. As always everything have pros and cons

Comment: `dev is sure that items won't change ` can you elaborate on this i'm interested to know (sample fiddle would be nice). cheers

Comment: @supercool for some odd reason when i still try this it is returning that selectedItem is not defined.

Comment: oh i see @072et i am happy to help but you can put something in fiddle on top to reproduce your issue . check casing & scope which may be the culprit .

Comment: @supercool i just realized what my issue is. I am using two different viewModels calling one within the other that is why it was seeing it as not defined. I did this: 'if: $parent.selectedItem....' and it worked fine from there. Thanks for all the help and effort.

Comment: humm anytime . glad your issue is resolved . good luck

Comment: @supercool but i did follow your structure in implementing so to be fair if you can submit your comment with the jsfiddle as an answer it would be great so i can mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments

**view:**

```
<select data-bind="options: items,optionsCaption:'-select-', value: selectedItem"></select>
<div data-bind="if:selectedItem() == 'A'" class="itemA">A</div>
<div data-bind="if:selectedItem() == 'B'" class="itemB">B</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.items = ko.observable(['A', 'B']);
   self.selectedItem = ko.observable(self.items()[0]);
};      
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26472/)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead:

```
//if selectedItem = 'A'
<div class="itemA">....</div>

//if selectedItem = 'B'
<div class="itemB">....</div>
```

Just do that:

```
<div data-bind="visible: selectedItem ">
```

Comment: For some reason it is telling me that 'selectedItem' is not defined

Comment: @072et have you defined selectedItem on your view model?

Comment: @072et - In your updated code I can see that you added observable 'selectedView', but probably you wanted to add 'selectedItem'

Comment: There is small subtle nuance: if you use "if" binding - if false, bindings inside will be not processed at all, if visible - all bindings inside is processed. For example, var selectedItem = ko.observable(null); and if you use visible, then binding data-bind="text: selectedItem.PropertyA" will produce exception. "If" binding will work as expected.

Comment: @VikciaR true but that is the advantage #performance perspective i.e if we don't want to show html there is no point of rendering it (Load Time saved) .

Comment: @super cool: I pointed there, that "IF" binding often is more suited for hiding parts of html, than hiding it with "VISIBLE" binding.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is not clear enough so I have assumed a few things.

**Check this fiddle: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/00c376gh/3/)**

If you are binding your select list then I would recommend using an object to be used as key value pair. Suppose you name your object **MyItem** which looks like this:

```
function MyItem(name, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

This will contain the text and value of your options in select, and your view model will look like this.

```
$(function () {

    function MyItem(name, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    function MyViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray
        ([
             new MyItem('A','a'), // 'A' will be option's text and 'a' will be option's value
             new MyItem('B','b')
        ]);

        self.selectedView = ko.observable();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
});
```

In your items, instead of adding plain array like ['A', 'B'], you can pass the object, And your Html will look like:

```
<select data-bind="options: items,value:selectedView,optionsText:'name', optionsValue:'value'"></select>
<div class="itemA" data-bind="visible:selectedView()=='a'">Div A</div>
<div class="itemB" data-bind="visible:selectedView()=='b'">Div B</div>
```